PHP parse first row of csv file to determine where to save data in subsequent rows
I am trying to extract data from spreadsheets sent to us by a customer, so we can save that data in our system.  Unfortunately the spreadsheets are not consistent, they have been adding and removing columns, making it difficult to create a single script to extract the data and save it.  On the plus side, they are using the same titles for each column on the spreadsheet.
My plan has been to process the first row with their titles and pair the column count with our database's column name.  I am currently saving it as an associated array.  The code sample below has had some case values removed for breviety.  The associative array has the column count as key, the name as value.
if (($handle = fopen($guestData, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $myArray = array();
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
      switch ($data[$c]) {
        case 'Customer ID':
          $myArray += [$c => "operatorBookingID"];
          break;
        case 'Customer Name':
          $myArray += [$c => "guestName"];
          break;
        case 'Country':
          $myArray += [$c => "nationality"];
          break;
        case 'Phone number':
          $myArray += [$c => "phone"];
          break;
        ' 
        '
        '
        }
      }
    } 

My first issue is that for some reason the first case doesn't register and doesn't get added to the array, even though it has the correct string.  The customer ID is always the first column of the spreadsheets we receive.  I end with with an array that starts like this:
 Array ( [3] => guestName [4] => nationality [5] => phone etc etc ) 

The spreadsheet are simple comma separated files, with double quotes around any data that contains commas.
edited
The previous error issue was resolved thanks to the second comment about the script closing the stream too early.

When you var_dump($data) for debugging, exactly what string does it show you in the first column? Have you checked ASCII values to make sure there isn't something hidden in there? Is it possible that the file starts with a byte-order marker and that is being pre-pended to the first column name? Does the fact that your sample array as shown starts at element three suggest that it's actually dropping more than the first column?

If the code is working for the first row of the CSV file, and failing for the subsequent rows, that suggests that something is either overwriting $handle, or closing the stream, before it can get to the second row.

var_dump($data) gives me a value for the first column [0]=&gt;   string(14) "Customer ID"

your array is not associative. it's a list. And you can get it by simply calling $myArray = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ","); before the main loop.

There's nothing in the code, that's in the question, that can tell us why $myArray doesn't contain an "operatorBookingID". We can only conclude that Customer ID probably doesn't occur in the header. It could be, for instance: 'Customer ID', despite you saying the file has double quotes? I just can't tell.

@KIKOSoftware  If you look at the csv with a text editor it shows Customer ID,Trip Name,Trip Start Date,Customer Name,Country,Phone number,...

If I get that CSV string, I do get the Customer ID. See: https://3v4l.org/HOtKC However, you would only get this for the first line of the CSV file. You seem to walk all the lines, trying to get the header. That's weird. I'm surprised you get anything at all. Anyway, you really should provide enough code in your question so we can replicate your problem. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. There are 2 benefits to this: 1. We can actually help you. 2. You might find the problem yourself first.

It's interesting that you say you get string(14) "Customer ID" - but you can see that the string "Customer ID" contains 11 characters, not 14. So does it possibly have three bytes at the start that you can't see, which might be the byte-order mark from the start of the file? Have you checked the ASCII values of the string, to see what's in there? I seem to recall asking that before. You could just get the first three bytes with fgetc() before you start using fgetcsv() and see if that makes any difference.

@droopsnoot Thanks for the extra suggestion.  Running fgetc() does show three diamonds.  Will have to figure out how to get around that next :)  Sorry not to understand your first reference to ASCII, I am an amateur not a pro coder.  Skipping other columns is correct as we don't save everything they send us.

Once you've retrieved the three characters by calling fgetc() three times, you can just carry on from there with your fgetcsv() calls, because they will start from wherever the file pointer is. Or you could read up on fseek() and just set the pointer three characters in as soon as you open the file.

Thanks fseek() did the job!  Wish I could mark your comment as the accepted answer.
